# (1/1) ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminController does not exist Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am doing MultiAuth in laravel 5.4 I create two tables one for users and the seonde for admins the authentification for usres works fine but when the admin login in it show me this error :

```
(1/1) ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminController does not exist
```

i don't know what is the reason for it, so here is my code :

AdminLoginController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Route;
use App\Admin;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['logout']]);
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
      return view('auth.admin_login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
      // Validate the form data
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
      ]);

      // Attempt to log the user in
      if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
      } 
      // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
      return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

AdminController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Admin;
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
    /**
     * show dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```